# How do I add a new element to an array at a certain section?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have the array

```
let mArray = [["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"], ["Candy", "Cake", "Chips"]]
```

How do I insert

```
"Popcorn"
```

so that the array will be

```
let mArray = [["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"], ["Candy", "Popcorn", "Cake", "Chips"]]
```

I just need to insert data into a certain section inside an array. Is this even possible??

Comment: Is the index is going to be fixed or going to vary ?

Comment: vary and I don't really need the Popcorn to be in a certain row of the section just to be in that specific section.

Comment: You should model your data differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare your array as var and then append in specific section and row:

```
    var mArray = [["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"], ["Candy", "Cake", "Chips"]]
    print(mArray)
    mArray[1].insert("PopCorn", at: 2)
    print(mArray)
```

**output:**

```
[["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"], ["Candy", "Cake", "Chips"]]
[["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"], ["Candy", "Cake", "PopCorn", "Chips"]]
```

Comment: follow up question, How do I get the amount of items in that second section? I've tried mArray[1].count but that doesn't seem possible

Comment: hmm... that does work I just don't know seem to know how to initialize an array that has a dynamic sections of a custom object

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
var mArray = [["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"], ["Candy", "Cake", "Chips"]]

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.mArray[1].append("Popcorn")
    print(mArray)
}
```

The output will be:

```
[["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"], ["Candy", "Cake", "Chips", "Popcorn"]]
```

Comment: yup that works too I just didn't realize you could do this mArray[1].

Comment: to get the number of items you have to put return self.mArray[1].count, and for you to be able to access the items in mArray[1] in cellForRowAt you have to use this self.mArray[1][indexPath.row].

Answer (score 0):

As the index not fixed. you can add following method

```
func getAppendedArr(section: Int,str: String) {
    var mArray = [["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"], ["Candy", "Cake", "Chips"]]
    var item = mArray[section]
    item.append(str)
    mArray[section] = item
}
```

and call it as follows :

```
getAppendedArr(section: 2, item: "Popcorn")
```